# Remove Every Other Element

Tags: objective-c

I have a large array (which I want to graph), and I want to reduce the size of it by removing every other element in it. If I have an array like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello",  @"Again", @"World", @"I", @"Test", @"All-Day", nil];
```

How would I be able to get it down to:

```
(Hello, World, Test)
```

Comment: When removing entries from an array it's usually a good idea to work from the back towards the front, so you don't confuse the indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution involving `removeObjectAtIndex:` is O(N^2), which you might not want since you said you “have a large array”.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (FG8_removeOddElements)

- (void)removeOddElements;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (FG8_removeOddElements)

- (void)removeOddElements {
    // Given (a, b, c), result is (a, c), so round up.
    NSUInteger finalCount = (self.count + 1) / 2;
    // Element 0 never moves so start at 1.
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < finalCount; ++i) {
        self[i] = self[i * 2];
    }
    [self removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(finalCount, self.count - finalCount)];
}

@end
```

Assuming `removeObjectsInRange:` is efficient, this performs the work in O(N) time.

### UPDATE

Since HotLicks seems to think this algorithm doesn't work, here's a test:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSMutableArray *array = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g"].mutableCopy;
    [array removeOddElements];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}

@end
```

And here's the output:

```
2014-05-08 15:23:44.123 tester[43347:303] (
    a,
    c,
    e,
    g
)
```

Comment: A solution using `removeObjectAtIndex` is *not* N^2.  In fact it's most certainly more efficient than `removeObjectsInRange`.  And I can't see how your solution would work at all.

Comment: @HotLicks `removeObjectAtIndex:` has to shift the remaining elements of the array down.  That is O(N).  Performing it N/2 times (to remove half the elements) makes the overall algorithm O(N^2).  You might think you can start at the high end of the array, but even so, eventually you will remove the object at index 1, and have to shift down all the remaining elements in the array (which are half as many as when you started, but still O(N)).

Comment: @HotLicks `removeObjectsInRange:` is O(N), but it is only performed once.  My loop is also O(N).  O(N) + O(N) = O(N).

Comment: I am removing all of the elements that were originally at odd indexes.  Try it out.  I have updated my answer with a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)removeEveryOtherElement:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSLog(@"Input array: %@", array);
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int x = 0; x<=array.count - 1; x++) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) { // if the index of the object is "even" (divisible by 2)
            [returnArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:x]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Returned array: %@", returnArray);
    return returnArray;
}
```

You have to watch out, because if you're performing operations on an `NSMutableArray` **the indices will change as you're adding and removing objects** (thus the problem with my first answer).

---

Output:

```
2014-05-08 16:14:14.693 test[2013:303] Input array: (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
)
2014-05-08 16:14:14.693 test[2013:303] Returned array: (
    0,
    2,
    4
)
```

Comment: You could just `x += 2` in the `for` loop instead of testing `x % 2 == 0` on each iteration.  (I'm not the down-voter.)

Comment: You could also traverse the array backwards - that usually solves the problem with removing objects while iterating :)